# JQuery data not sending correctly to CFC

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

So for the life of me I can't figure out why my CFC function is not running...firefug says it runs, but nothing happens.

```
   <cffunction name="deleteRequest" access="remote" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="id" type="numeric" required="yes">

    <cfquery name = "deleteRequests" datasource = "#application.dsn#">
    DELETE FROM requests
    WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value = "#id#">
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn>
</cffunction>
```

JQUERY/javascript:

```
        $("input[name=delete]").click(function(){
        var z = deleteRequest($(this).attr("id")); 
        var y = $(this).attr("id");
        if(z){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cfc/request.cfc',
        data: {id: y, method: "deleteRequest"}
        });
        } 
     }); 

      function deleteRequest(id){
        var x = confirm("Are you SURE you want to DELETE this?");
        if(x){return 1;}
        return 0;
      }
```

The jquery is working...and it is sending it and supposedly  getting there...but nothing happens. I tested the CFC and invoked it manually and it works. I'm guessing it is something to do with my variables. I thought maybe the id needed parseInt() but that didn't help either.

All it should do is delete the entry from the DB. What am I doing wrong?

*Sorry for the simple question. I have a lot of trouble with JQUERY+CFC...I have been looking for good tutorials...but I can never seem to find any good beginner ones.

UPDATE: Tried changing url to have the method param in it and changed the access to public...still the same results.

Comment: Are you using Firebug (or similar) to inspect the POST data being sent to the CFC?  Or, have you tried a cfdump/cfabort on your form scope inside the CFC to see what is coming across from jQuery?

Comment: I've done firebug...and it says it is posting the correct data id=299 and the method param. I have yet to be successful in getting the cfc to dump anything. (It is almost like it is ignoring it.) Same results after changing it to ?method=deleteRequest and public. Although it works if I invoke it, just not with the jquery call. Do you think it could be some kind of server setting?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
<cffunction name="deleteRequest" access="public" returntype="void">

    <cfquery name = "deleteRequests" datasource = "#application.dsn#">
    DELETE FROM requests
    WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value = "#id#">
    </cfquery>

<cfreturn>
</cffunction>

 $("input[name=delete]").click(function(){
    var z = deleteRequest($(this).attr("id")); 
    var y = $(this).attr("id");
    if(z){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cfc/request.cfc?method=deleteRequest',
    data: {id: y}
    });
    } 
 }); 

  function deleteRequest(id){
    var x = confirm("Are you SURE you want to DELETE this?");
    if(x){return 1;}
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: i think you need to mark your function with "public" instead of "remote" ... pls try this.. more informations => http://blog.nitorsys.com/ajax-call-to-coldfusion-component-using-jquery/

Comment: Setting it to public did not work. :( Also, I thought for ajax stuff it should be set to remote? (I also tried combining both of these solutions, no go as well.)

Comment: does http://blog.nitorsys.com/ajax-call-to-coldfusion-component-using-jquery/ not help ?

Comment: maybe a stupid question but. your cfc is in the webfolder not in customtags ?

Comment: it's actually in a web folder named /cas/resourcerequest/dev/cfc/request.cfc  but i redacted that information. Firebug says it finds the page, so I didn't think that was the issue. :\ (my code actually has /cas/resourcerequest/dev/cfc/request.cfc as the url)

Comment: I got it work in a regular .cfm... same query. :\ If anyone can figure this out I'd be extremely happy!

Answer (score 0):

We use this style of call quite heavily in our applications with little trouble. Looking at the code, we tend to use the style dknaack suggested, with the method name in the URL but the data supplied as arguments.
Have you tried using Fiddler (fiddler2.com) to intercept the calls to make sure it's definitely calling your code.
Other than that, I' d make use of `<CFLOG>` in your method to record what it's being passed, or the debugger if you're set up to use it.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think I have access to to the log directory...I don't maintain our server. :|  I'll look into fiddler.

Comment: what is difference between fiddler and firebug?

Comment: difference between Fiddler and FireBug is that Fiddler is a separate Debugging proxy, meaning you can run it for IE, Chrome and FF all at the same time. Any program that supports proxies can be used through it (including `<CFHTTP>`) and it's got some very powerful features for inspecting requests and responses. It saves my bacon on a daily basis :)